# Find best approximation of $\sin(\pi x)$ over $[0,1]$ with quadratic polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Use the theory of orthogonal functions to find best in the mean approximation of the function $\sin(πx)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ by a second-order polynomial

That is, find such coefficients $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$ that,

$$\int^1_0 (\sin(\pi x)-a_0-a_1x-a_2x^2)^2 \, dx, $$

takes a minimal possible value.

I feel as though this has something to do with Fourier series but I really cant be sure because I am not very familiar with this area.

Also, I'm not sure what "best in mean approximation" means, so any help with that would be great.

Comment: What does 'best in the mean' mean?

Comment: just edited to say that im not actually sure what that means and is partly why im stuck

Comment: The question tells you exactly what to do, even if you don't understand the terms.

Comment: What happens when you multiply out and evaluate that integral?

Comment: Are you familiar with shifted Legendre polynomials?

Comment: One approach would be to use Gram Schmidt to orthonormalise the functions $x \mapsto 1, x \mapsto x, x \mapsto x^2$ and then take the inner product with $ x \mapsto \sin ( \pi x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is equivalent of finding the projection of $f : \rightarrow \sin(\pi x) $ on the vectorial space $F\triangleq \operatorname{Vect}(1,\mathrm{Id},\mathrm{Id}^2)=R_2[X]$ and calculating the distance of $f$ to $F$

In order to do this decompose the projection of $f$ which is

$$ P_F(f) = a_0 + a_1X+ a_2X^2 $$

On the normalized base relatively to your scalar product (you have to Schmidt the canonical of $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ relatively to your scalar product).

And find the coefficient of $P_F(f) $ in your Schmited basis, those are consequently linked to your $a_0,a_1,a_2$

---

Once you find it, compute

$$d(f, F)^2=\|f-P_F(f)\|^2$$

which is your integral squared, minimized by the definition of the projection.

Furthermore,

We call *mean* approximation because it is an average made through an integral (which plays the role of "continuous" averages when we need it instead of summing, here your interval has a mesure of $1$ so it is an average (sum divided by the amplitude of number we take)

Don't hesitate if you need precision.

Comment: That's the idea, but the basis that you write is not orthonormal, so you'd have to Gram-Schmidt this before computing the coefficients.

Comment: Yes I think of it when I woke up today ! I mod it !

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int^1_0 ( & \sin(\pi x)-a_0-a_1x-a_2x^2)^2 \, dx, \\[8pt]
= \int_0^1 \Big( & \sin^2(\pi x) \,dx + a_0^2 + a_1^2 x^2 + a_2^2 x^4 \\
& {}-2a_0\sin(\pi x) - 2a_1x\sin(\pi x) - 2a_2x^2 \sin (\pi x) \\
& {} -{}2a_0a_1 x -2a_0a_2x^2 -2a_1a_2 x^2 \Big) \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \sin ^2(\pi x)\, dx + a_0^2 \int_0^1 1\,dx + a_1^2 \int_0^2x^2\, dx + a_2^2\int_0^1 x^2\,dx \\[10pt]
& {} - 2a_0 \int_0^1\sin(\pi x)\,dx - 2a_1 \int_0^1 x\sin(\pi x)\,dx - 2a_2 \int_0^1 x^2 \sin(\pi x)\,dx \\[10pt]
& {} - 2a_0a_1 \int_0^1 x\,dx -2a_0a_2 \int_0^1 x^2\, dx - 2a_1 a_2 \int_0^1 x^2 \, dx \\[12pt]
= {} & B_0 + B_1a_0^2 + B_2a_1^2 + B_3 a_2^2 - 2B_4 a_0 - 2B_5 a_1 -2B_6 a_2 \\
& {} -2B_7 a_0 a_1 - 2B_8 a_0 a_2 - 2B_9 a_1 a_2.  
\end{align}
So you have a quadratic polynomial in three variables and the problem is to find the values of the variables that minimize the value of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x \mapsto x^k$, $k=0,1,...$ is a Schauder basis for $L^2[0,1]$. If we use, say, Gram Schmidt to orthonormalise these to get $e_k$ then we know that
for any $f \in L^2[0,1]$, we have
$f = \sum_{k=0}^n \langle e_k, f \rangle e_k$ (in an $L^2$ sense). Furthermore, the best approximation to $f$ in an $L^2$ sense in the subspace spanned by $e_0,...,e_n$ is given by $\sum_{k=0}^n \langle e_k, f \rangle e_k$.

So, with $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x),g(x) dx $, we get
$e_0(x) = 1$, $e_1(x)=2 \sqrt{3}(x-{1 \over 2})$,
$e_2(x) = 6 \sqrt{5}(x^2-x+{1 \over 6})$. (These are the normalised shifted Legendre polynomials.)

With $f(x) = \sin ( \pi x)$, we get
$\langle e_0, f \rangle = {2 \over \pi}$,
$\langle e_1, f \rangle = 0$,
$\langle e_2, f \rangle = {2 \sqrt{5} \over \pi^3} (\pi^2-12)$,
and so the best $L^2$ approximation is
$\sum_{k=0}^2 \langle e_k, f \rangle e_k(x) = {( 60 {{\pi }^{2}}-720 ){{x}^{2}} +( 720-60{{\pi }^{2}} ) x -120+12 {\pi^{2}} \over {{\pi }^{3}}}$.

Comment: how do you know that the normalised shifted Legendre polynomials are needed for this question, and how do you determine them?

Comment: Well, it just happened along the way. If you start with the functions $x \mapsto 1, x \mapsto x, ...$ and use Gram Schmidt to orthogonalise them then you end up with the shifted Legendre polynomials. It is just a name, I didn't start by thinking that I needed to use the Legendre polynomials, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Take the advantage of the symmetry to express

$$\sin(\pi x) = p+ q\>(\frac12-t)^2$$

Minimize

\begin{align}
f(p,q)&= \int_0^{\frac12} [p+ q\>(\frac12-x)^2 - \sin(\pi x)]^2dt\\
& =\frac12p^2 + \frac1{12} pq  +\frac1{160}q^2-\frac2\pi p+\frac{8-\pi^2 }{2\pi^3}q+\frac14
\end{align}

by setting 
$$f_p’=p+\frac1{12}q-\frac2\pi=0,\>\>\>
f_q’=\frac1{12}p+\frac1{80}q+ \frac{8-\pi^2 }{2\pi^3} =0
$$

to obtain the optimal coefficients $p= \frac{60-3\pi^2 }{\pi^3},\> q= \frac{60(\pi^2 -12)}{\pi^3}$. Thus,

$$\sin(\pi x) =  \frac{60-3\pi^2 }{\pi^3}+\frac{60(\pi^2 -12)}{\pi^3}\left(\frac12-x\right)^2$$

as shown in the plots below

[image]