# How to find closest trigonometric polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Could you give me any hints?

How to find the trigonometric polynomial of the third order closest to the function:

$f(x) \in L_{2\pi}^2, \,f(x) = \text{sgn}(x), \quad x \in (-\pi, \pi)$  in the norm $L_{2\pi}^2$ ?

Comment: It is an optimization system :
I made a similar answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3665551/763728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek a trigonometric polynomial of the form
\begin{equation}
P(x)=\frac{a_0}{2} + a_1\cos(x) + a_2 \cos(2x) + a_3\cos(3x) +b_1\sin(x) +b_2\sin(2x) +b_3\sin(3x)
\end{equation}
such that minimizes $||f-P||_{L^2_{2\pi}}$.

Now, it's only necessary project the function $f$ in the subspace generated by the orthogonal bases $\{1/2, \cos(x), \cos(2x), \cos(3x), \sin(x), \sin(2x), \sin(3x)\}$, using the scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{L^2_\pi}$. So we have that 
$$a_0 = \frac{(f,1/2)}{||1/2||_{L^2_{2\pi}}}$$
$$a_1 = \frac{(f,\cos(x))}{||\cos(x)||_{L^2_{2\pi}}}$$
$$b_1 = \frac{(f,\sin(x))}{||\sin(x)||_{L^2_{2\pi}}}$$
$$a_2 = \frac{(f,\cos(2x))}{||\cos(2x)||_{L^2_{2\pi}}}$$
and so on for others coefficients.

Comment: It would be better to use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ rather than $\frac{1}{2}$